# 777 permissions on NTFS-3G Windows mount

Tags: mount, permissions, steam, external-hdd

I'm trying to install a game from Steam on an external harddrive.

I normally use this to mount my WD Elements external usb harddrive (windows share): `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/elements/`

I've tried the following: `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/elements/ -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000` which was stated in this question: [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Still getting `New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions`.

I would like like 777 permissions on the external harddrive.

Comment: See the third answer there: http://askubuntu.com/a/17301/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/elements/ -o fmask=0000,dmask=0000,umask=0000
```